# Can I use the ST Monad inside a Get Monad (from Data.Binary)

Tags: haskell, monads

What I am trying to write Binary instances for Vectors.

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as MV
import Data.Binary


instance (Binary a) => Binary (V.Vector a) where
    put = vput
    get = vget
```

The implementation is: first output the length and then all of the data points

```
vput v = (put (V.length v)) >> (put `V.mapM_` v)
```

The problem is with `vget`. I would like to use `V.create` (I am planning on outputting very large vectors and the semantics seem like a very good fit.

Here is my attempt:

```
vget :: (Binary a) => Get (V.Vector a)
vget = do
    size <- get
    vec <- liftM V.create $ do
        v <- (liftM MV.new) size
        forM_ [0..(size-1)] $ \i -> do
            val <- get
            (liftM3 MV.write) v i val
        return v -- This is line 22
    return vec
```

The error is

```
SerializeVector.hs:22:16:
    Couldn't match expected type `forall s. ST s (MV.MVector s a0)'
            with actual type `Get a10'
```

I have been trying to reason this through and also randomly inserting `liftM`s, but to no avail.

Comment: You'd need to use `runST` to actually execute the `ST` monad code, no?

Comment: V.create has type

``create :: (forall s. ST s (MVector s a)) -> Vector a``

their example is

``create (do { v <- new 2; write v 0 'a'; write v 1 'b' }) = <a,b>``.
http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9.1/doc/html/Data-Vector.html

Comment: You won't be able to call `get` from in the `ST` monad, since that would need to be an ST transformer.

Comment: So, you are saying it's impossible to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to compose two monads: `ST` and `Get`.

```
   vec <- liftM V.create $ do
        v <- (liftM MV.new) size
        forM_ [0..(size-1)] $ \i -> do
            val <- get                -- run an action in the `Get` monad
            (liftM3 MV.write) v i val -- write it in the `ST` monad
```

This just isn't possible. You'd need an `ST` transformer to allow you run calls to `get` from your `ST` action. You might be able to use either an `ST` transformer monad package, or stream lazily a sequence of reads from the get monad into the ST builder.

Comment: I was trying to get a ``Get (ST s (MV.MVector a))`` monad.

Comment: You can certainly `runST` in the `Get` monad. What you can't do is call `Get` actions inside `ST`. To do that, you'd have to `runGet` on the current buffer.

Answer (score 6):

Can't you use `V.replicateM` to fill the `Vector`?

```
vget :: (Binary a) => Get (V.Vector a)
vget = get >>= (`V.replicateM` get)
```